# Is there an iPhone app that takes continuous photos?

Tags: iphone, ios, software-recommendation, photos

I am looking for an app that can take continuous photos.  In other words, I should be able to set the interval (e.g. every 3 seconds) and for how long (e.g. 2 minutes) and it would just snap photos.

Does something like that exists?

Answer (score 1):

Try Triggertrap, it has time lapse and other options to trigger a photo. It works with the iPhone's camera or, if you purchase the appropriate cable, you can hook it up to a dslr. The free version is limited but I think provides the functionality you're looking for.

[Triggertrap Mobile](https://triggertrap.com/products/triggertrap-mobile/)

Answer (score 1):

I've used iTimeLapse a couple times and it seems pretty good.

[iTimeLapse Pro](http://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/itimelapse-pro-time-lapse/id335866860?mt=8)

Answer (score 0):

If you can update to iOS 8, then you can have this Time Lapse feature for free from Apple.